# Degrees of freedom used by emmeans after fitting a model in glmmTMB

Tags: r, emmeans, glmmtmb

I recently noticed that emmeans uses the residual degrees of freedom when calculating a confidence interval after fitting a glm in glmmTMB, even when there is no dispersion parameter (and hence only fixed effects).

This differs from standard practice, where the degress of freedom would be set to Inf, as happens when emmeans is used after fitting such a model with glm(.).

I can understand why one might want to do this (a bit more conservatism in the interval, to allow for the fact that df=Inf is justified by asymptotics), but I thought I should check what the glmmTMB team had in mind when they chose this option.

I contacted Russell Lenth, who maintains emmeans, and he suggested I discuss it with the glmmTMB team.

Comment: This is fundamentally about a statistical issue rather than a specific programming question. Such questions are a better fit for [stats.se] rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: A better way to get feedback from the `glmmTMB` team would be to raise on issue on the github project site: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In line with MrFlick's comment I have now put my query here: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/893

Answer (score 0):

This "infelicity" is fixed in the development version of `glmmTMB` and will be fixed on CRAN the next time we release: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/893